# "Missing [super dealloc]" warning in an ARC project

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I've refactored a project to ARC. It looks fine, but there is an object which uses the notification center. I removed the observer in a custom dealloc method. That worked fine in the non ARC project. It also works in ARC, but I get a crazy warning: "Method possibly missing a [super dealloc] call." In an ARC project it is automatically done for me, when the method ends. Even better: I must not call it in ARC projects! This must be an XCode bug, right? Here's my code:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    // [super dealloc]; will be called automatically
}
```

I always want to write code that doesn't throw warnings. Is there a way around that yellow exclamation mark?

Comment: There shouldn't be any warning, as you suspected. Are you sure you turned off ARC properly?

Comment: I turned ARC on! I used the Edit / Refactor / Convert to Objective-C ARC... menu.

Comment: Make sure that specific implementation file does not build without ARC support - check Build-Phases->Compile Sources for that.

Comment: The file with the warning should build with ARC (no compiler flags entered). There are other files with the -fno-objc-arc flag, though.

Comment: Have you cleaned and deleted derived data and everything?

Comment: Yes, I did.
The problem was solved meanwhile... but thanks for the reminder. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the following lines into your dealloc method to make sure it is compiled with ARC enabled:

```
#if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
#error "ARC is off"
#endif
```

If you get the compiler error when building, you're sure that ARC is off and have to search for the reason. It's probably in per-file build settings in your target.

Comment: OK, here's the answer to that riddle: The project has two targets and the refactoring only changed the "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" flag in the Build Settings of one target to YES. So the other one threw that warning. Switched it to YES by myself, and now it works. 

Thanks, guys!

Comment: Also I just discovered that if you turn on ARC for the project while viewing the target, the target will still be set to NO. You need to enable ARC for each target individually it appears.

Answer (score 1):

I did resolved this warning by following steps:

1. Click target(`<yourapp>.xcodeproj`) in which the file(`<classname>.m`) class shows above warning
2. Select **TARGET** >> **Build Phases** >> **Compile sources**
3. Search file
4. Add **Compiler Flags** `-fobjc-arc`

This is looks like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*"Have you tried turning it off and on again?"*

This is a silly answer, but cleaning the target ***and restarting Xcode*** has solved this very irritating behavior for me

- Menu > Product > Clean
- Menu > Product > (press the alt key) Clean Project Folder
- restart Xcode

After that, I got more ARC related warnings, so clearly, Xcode wasn't finished converting to ARC. Now the warning is gone and everything works just fine.