# Build Objective-C Library with CMake with ARC enabled

Tags: objective-c, cmake

I am trying to build an Objective-C ARC enabled library using CMake. When using the "Unix Makefiles" generator I run into a warning:

> method possibly missing a [super dealloc] call

I don't run into this warning when using the XCode generator. Is there a flag I can pass to CMake to make sure that the command line build also recognizes this to be an ARC build and not have that warning generated?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to let CMake know that you want to build the project with ARC. Otherwise, it will show the warning.

**Option 1**

However, `CTSetObjCArcEnabled` is only available only if we have cmake-toolkit installed. If it is not installed, you can use the following:

```
set_property (TARGET target_name APPEND_STRING PROPERTY 
              COMPILE_FLAGS "-fobjc-arc")
```

**Option 2 (deprecated since 3.0)**

Use `CTSetObjCARCEnabled`. Reference is available [here](http://nickhutchinson.me/cmake-toolkit/):

> Enables or disables Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting on a per-directory, per-target or per-source basis.

```
CTSetObjCARCEnabled(<value>  
        <DIRECTORY | TARGETS targets... | SOURCES sources... >)
```

**Useful Tip**

Also, as recommended from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12159090/1035008), it is helpful to use the following to make sure the project is compiled with ARC enabled:

```
#if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
#error "ARC is off"
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks. CTSetObjCArcEnabled is available only if we have cmake-toolkit installed. However, following the source code of cmake-toolkit, I found the relevant code - set_property (TARGET target_name APPEND_STRING PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS "-fobjc-arc")

Comment: @georgemp, thanks for sharing the knowledge! I have also updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Not longer maintained: "Ye olde warning: This repo is no longer maintained, and dates from when I was first learning CMake a few years back; modern (post 3.0)" (https://github.com/nickhutchinson/cmake-toolkit) The second option could become the first

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach is to specify per-target compiler flags. This could be considered more inline with modern CMake:

```
target_compile_options(target_name PUBLIC "-fobjc-arc")
```

**Note**: using `PUBLIC` will transitively forward this compiler flag to other targets depending on this one. Replacing by `PRIVATE` will prevent this propagation.

Answer (score 3):

XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC works for me. See https://github.com/forexample/testapp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

```
set_target_properties(
    ${APP_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE YES
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC YES  
)
```

Comment: This will only work if you generate Xcode project and use Xcode to build it. If you use other generators, like Makefiles or Ninja, this property will have no effect.

Comment: If you are using this method and want only a particular file compiled without automatic reference counting then use `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag: `set_property(SOURCE file.cpp APPEND_STRING PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS "-fno-objc-arc")`

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you want all Objective-C(++) files to be built with ARC:

```
set(CMAKE_OBJC_FLAGS "-fobjc-arc")
set(CMAKE_OBJCXX_FLAGS "-fobjc-arc")
```